# Textview between action bar's title and action bar's tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to ask whether there is a way to put a `TextView` between the title in the action bar and the tabs in the action bar. It has to be on it's own separate line. 
The other way is to implement tabs with the `TabHost` and put the view above it, but I will have a hard time making tabs look like the tabs in the `ActionBar`, because by design they have to be like them.

Comment: What about `actionBar.setSubtitle()`?

Comment: and what about this **actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);** where custom bar can be manipulated according to need